# Using D&D issue when click on item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Im using D&D from list box to textBox and the problem is that the you can just click on item(the item marked with blue color)
let say the first item in the list and then you can go to the list and with the mouse drag different item, let say the last in the list, but the item that was actually dragged is the item which you selected via click i.e. the first item.
In debug you can see that the item which you get in the following code is first item
you clicked and marked as blue and not the item that you actually dragged, any idea how to solve it?

you can click and mark any item on the listBox but drag different item while the previous item is marked with blue color...

```
var listBox = sender as ListBox;

if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    var mySelectedItem = listBox.SelectedItem as User;
    ...
```

Comment: Could you paste some code how are you initiating drag'n'drop action?

Comment: You can't even be bothered to type out Drag and Drop? Really? Seems like people can't be bothered to answer your question either. Perhaps if you bothered to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then you would have had an answer by now?

Answer (score 0):

In a Drag and Drop operation, *you* select what data gets used:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, data, DragDropEffects);
```

What data you use is completely up to *you*. So if you find that you have set the wrong value into the `data` field, *that's* what you have to fix.

There *are* other ways of detecting what control was clicked on... try something like this:

```
HitTestResult hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(containingUIElement, 
    e.GetPosition(containingUIElement));
Control controlUnderMouse = hitTestResult.VisualHit.GetParentOfType<Control>();
```